# Ford Edge SE 2016 Wheel Noise

Tags: ford, noise, edge

Have a Ford Edge SE 2016 where while driving,there is this rattling sound from the right rear tire.  This only happens when we reach about 55 miles per hour and above.  My assumption is the brake pads need changed but an wondering if anyone else knows more than my assumption from the sound it is making.  May have started a month or 2 ago.

Below is the link to an audio file I recorded.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1766Cw2TmoFV9yUvLrt68FUPd2igVnMDC/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could be the lug nuts are loose, could be the wheel bearing, could be a pebble in the hubcap.